# performace issue of std::vector in php (using swig)

Tags: php, performance, vector, swig

I have custom language parser in C++ and I created an interface for PHP and Python using SWIG. It exposes the AST back into target language.
It works pretty well, already the PHP using C++ lib is 30% faster, but it seems the bottleneck is tree traversing.
In pure PHP, the amount of time spent printing the results is trivial, but using the C++ library, that is majority of runtime of the script.
Right now my AST's nodes can have "unlimited" amount of children (n-ary tree).
For access to child nodes I created 2 functions

```
Node* getChild(int i) {
    return self->getChildren().at(i).get();
}

int getNumChildren() {
    return self->getChildren().size();
}
```

so the traversing in PHP looks like this

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $node->getNumChildren(); ++$i)
    doSomething($node->getChild($i));
```

I tried using the std_vector.i SWIG template as soon as I learned about it, but it didn't seem to help.
Would it help if I modified my code so it creates binary tree instead? Or is there another problem I'm not seeing?
I can provide more of my code if needed.
Thanks

Edit: it seems the tree traversing using C++ lib is around 2 times slower than using pure PHP implementation (which obviously uses PHP arrays for storing children) - 20 vs 10 seconds

Comment: Cross language calls are expensive in all probability. I'd recommend moving `doSomething` into C++ also and aim to return just a single buffer/object/string when all is done.

Comment: Sadly that's not really possible since that's a function that extracts relevant information from the tree and uses them somehow and that's up to user of the library how he uses that information.

Comment: But I will probably just return a tree in JSON format since that seems to be the fastest solution.